# Finding the sum of the series $\sum\limits_{j>i=1}^{2n}(-1)^{i+j}$

Tags: real-analysis, summation

I have to find the sum

$\sum\limits_{j>i=1}^{2n}(-1)^{i+j}$.

Please anyone help me how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried small cases ($n=1, 2$ or $3$) ?

Comment: What is meant by $j>i=1$ ?

Comment: Do not use the `self-learning` or `education` tags for questions about a specific math problem.  Those tags are meant to be used for questions about pedagogy, the topic of how learning actually occurs.  It is meant for something like "*I'm studying on my own rather than in a classroom.  Should I take tests?  If I do, how could I even get them graded?*"  They are not meant to be used as tags for a question just because that question came up during your studies.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I interpret the notation to be shorthand for $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n}\sum\limits_{j=i+1}^{2n}(-1)^{i+j}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes it means the same.

Comment: In the pairs $(1,2)$, $(1,3)$, ... $(1, 2n)$ there is one more pair with odd sum than number of pairs with even sum. Continue up and see the result.

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, the answer always is $-n$. Is there any formal proof?

Comment: @user587389 If you can see it is $-n$ then I'm not really sure what is your question.

Comment: @JMoravitz: I found it simpler to compute $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{2n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{j-1}(-1)^{i+j}$

Comment: @robjohn What makes it simpler?

Comment: @JMoravitz: I find it easier to sum from the bottom ($i=1$) than from the top; e.g. $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{j-1}(-1)^{i+j}=-\frac{1+(-1)^j}2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One elegant way how to see the result may be this. The sum over all $i,j$ such that $1\leq i,j \leq 2n$ is obviously $0$. Split it to three parts $<$, $=$ and $>$ and you get the equation $x + 2n + x = 0$

Comment: [+1] Nice answer...

Comment: Yes, I was looking for something like this. Thanks a lot, Sir.

Answer (score 1):

As the terms cancel each other in pairs,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\sum_{j=i+1}^{2n}(-1)^{i+j}=\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\sum_{j=i+1}^{2n}(-1)^{i+j}=-\sum_{i=1}^{2n}(i\bmod2)=-n.$$